# How do I get the value of an object from one window into another window's class with Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt

This seems like it should be a simple question. I have two QSpinBoxes in my MainWindow, with a push button beside them. The user first selects the dimensions of an array of checkboxes using these spin boxes, then clicks the push button. This pops up a new window with the array of checkboxes in it. The problem I am having though is that when I try to get the value of the spinboxes in my popup window's code, I get a compiler error because these buttons are private. Here is the code:

```
void DomainGeneration::createBoxes()
{
    int x_dim = MainWindow::ui->xDim->value();
    int y_dim = MainWindow::ui->yDim->value();
......the code......
}
```

Compiler errors:

> 'Ui::MainWindow* MainWindow::ui' is
>   private within this context

and

> object missing in reference to
>   'MainWindow::ui' from this location

So my question is, how do I access these objects from a different window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. `MainWindow::ui` is private
2. `MainWindow::ui` is not static, you need an actual instance of a MainWindow to reach it

To solve one, you usually create accessor methods in the `MainWindow` (or whatever class it is that needs to export some of its state).

To solve two, you need a pointer to your `MainWindow` instance to call these accessors on.

In your MainWindow class, define something like:

```
int getXDim() const { return ui->xDim->value(); }
```

And to get the pointer to your main window, either pass it in to your DomainGeneration's constructor, or into that `createBoxes()` method, depending on how/where those are called and whether or not you'll need that pointer elsewhere in that class.

Something like:

```
void DomainGeneration::createBoxes(MainWindow const* main)
{
  int x_dim = main->getXDim();
  ...
}
```

(Or just pass the dimensions to that methods, obviously.)

(None of this is Qt specific. This is plain C++.)

Comment: You should very much just pass the information in.  You have it when you call the constructor of the new dialog, so just pass it along.